# Taylor Series $\sin(3x)$ centered at $a=\frac{\pi}{6}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Using a table I got
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n & f^{n}(x) & f^{n}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) \\
\hline
0 & \sin(3x) & 1\\
1 & 3\cos(3x) & 0\\
2 & -9\sin(3x) & -9\\
3 & -27\cos(3x) & 0\\
4 & 81\sin(3x) & 81
\end{array}

From this table, I expanded $\sin(3x)$ centered at $a=\frac{\pi}{6}$, I get
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{0!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^0+\frac{0}{1!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^1-\frac{9}{2!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^2+\frac{0}{3!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^3+\frac{81}{4!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^4+\cdots \\
&= \frac{1}{0!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^0+\cancel{\frac{0}{1!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^1}-\frac{9}{2!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^2+\cancel{\frac{0}{3!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^3}+\frac{81}{4!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^4+\cdots \\
&= \frac{1}{0!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^0-\frac{3^2}{2!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^2+\frac{3^4}{4!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^4-\frac{3^6}{6!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^6
\end{align}

Is the following Taylor Series correct for the function $f(x)=\sin(3x)$ centered at $a=\frac{\pi}{6}$?
\begin{align}
f(x) &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{3^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^{2n-2}
\end{align}

Comment: The title of the post mentions $\frac\pi2$, but the body mentions $\frac\pi6$.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. The correct value for $a$ is $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: Shouldn’t you multiply RHS by -1?

Comment: Substitute $u=x - \frac \pi 6$, then you have simply $\cos(3u)$.

Comment: This is wrong, the first term in your formula is $-1,$ when it should be $1.$ It should be $(-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: Good catch Thomas, thank you!

Comment: It’s better to start at $n=0$ for a Taylor series. In this case, it is easier, too. Just take $m=n-1$ and then the sum is $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This seems to be the answer you'll get with/without the table. Just that without, you'd have to work out the values of different derivatives of *f* but you would ultimately arrive that result.

Comment: Is it okay that the series starts at 1 or do I have to start the series at 0?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The series starts at 1.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, but it is simpler to do it as follows:\begin{align}\sin(3x)&=\sin\left(3\left(x-\frac\pi6\right)+\frac\pi2\right)\\&=\cos\left(3\left(x-\frac\pi6\right)\right)\end{align}and now, since$$\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n},$$you have\begin{align}\sin(3x)&=\cos\left(3\left(x-\frac\pi6\right)\right)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n3^n}{(2n)!}\left(x-\frac\pi6\right)^{2n}.\end{align}

Comment: Isn't that what MartinR suggested?

Comment: I've checked and, yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly easier approach.

Letting $y=x-\frac{\pi}6$ then:

$$\begin{align}\sin(3x)&=\sin\left(3\left(y+\frac{\pi}6\right)\right)\\
&=\sin\left(3y+\frac{\pi}2\right)\\
&=\sin(3y)\cos\frac{\pi}2+\cos(3y)\sin\frac{\pi}2\\
&=\cos(3y)
\end{align}$$

Now we use the standard power series for $\cos w$ at $w=0.$